# Mouse's cursor size is not saved in Lubuntu 21.10

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, 21.10

In **LXQT Settings** is option for changing mouse cursor size in Xorg (LXQT Settings->Keyboard and Mouse->Cursor https://drive.google.com/file/d/15bjIeK11kQV-WeTG5DbuMF6c6SndUXQG/view?usp=sharing) . But after reboot, cursor returns to it's initial size.

How to save this setting permanently?

Regards.

Comment: Are your settings being saved in `~/config/lxqt/session.conf`.  If I make changes, I see them reflected in that file - which is how they'll survive reboot.  Is your system an installed one?   Do you own that file? (ie. haven't made a change whilst had elevated privileges (eg. changes made via `sudo` or equivalent forcing you to no longer have write access to that file).

Comment: @guiverc In ~/.config/lxqt/session.conf there is setting: `cursor_size=44` but cursor has size 22. Maybe this is a bug ?

Comment: If I make changes to mine; it's reflected in that file straight away...   (*I'm currently on jammy but I can't see that would make any difference, as LXQt 1.0.0 hasn't reached my system yet.. so I'm still using 0.17 like you*)  Did you check the file ownership?   I'll endeavor to check a standard *impish* box later when I have time, but I'm not convinced it's a bug yet...

Comment: I had the same reaction on a *pre-release* QA-test install of *impish* (dell_opt_780 on https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/release-team/testing-checklist/); changes to mouse theme & size are reflected immediately in the file without  issue.  I'd check file (`stat`) permissions on your system; No I don't think it's a bug - if you file one I'll look though.

Comment: @guiverc In lubuntu jammy daily build, installed in virtualbox I have the same issue. Cursor size is stored in session.conf, but not applied after reboot:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UZ9bW37_lUZIAfG1c7XeGLooSY8o-1Se/view?usp=sharing Permision of session.conf looks normal: rw-rw-r--

Comment: Please file a bug and I'll re-test & explore the issue further.    (`lxqt-config` is what I'd file against; https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/)

Comment: Ok, reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxqt-config/+bug/1950691

Comment: Thanks; you beat it appearing in my IRC client window (*it just did*), and it's yet to appear in my email client.  Thank you for ensuring I didn't miss it.